# How do you Auto Forward email based 'To' field in outlook?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I tried to write the code as below

- Case 1: If the mail is sent TO A@f.com -> AutoForward To A@x.com
- Case 2: If the mail is sent TO A@f.com B@f.com C@f.com -> AutoForward To A@x.com B@x.com

Could you please help me how to code in
Case 2: If the mail is sent TO A@f.com B@f.com C@f.com -> AutoForward To A@x.com B@x.com

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem 
Set myFwd = Item.Forward 

Dim xStr1 As String
Dim xStr2 As String
Dim Recipient As String

Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients 
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient 
Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _ 
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" 
Set recips = mail.Recipients 
For Each recip In recips 

    'Case 1: If the mail is sent TO A@x.com'
    If recip = "A@x.com" Then
        Set ToMember = myFwd.Recipients.Add ("A@f.com")
        Set CcMember = myFwd.Recipients.Add ("A@f.com") 
        CcMember.Type = 2
    
    'Case 2: If the mail is sent TO A@x.com B@x.com C@x.com'
    ElseIf recip = "A@x.com" "B@x.com" "C@x.com" Then
        Recipient = "@f.com"
        Recipient = "B@f.com"
        Recipient = "C@f.com"
        xStr1 = "<p>B1</p>" 
        xStr2 = "<p>B2</p>"
    Else
        MsgBox "None of the conditions was true, abort."
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

myFwd.Recipients.Add Recipient 
myFwd.HTMLBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HTMLBody 

myFwd.Send 
Set myFwd = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Put the most restrictive condition first.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As mailitem)

Dim myFwd As mailitem
Set myFwd = Item.Forward
    
Dim xStr1 As String
Dim xStr2 As String

' If the mail is sent TO A@f.com B@f.com C@f.com -> AutoForward To A@x.com B@x.com
If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase("A@f.com")) Then
    If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase("B@f.com")) Then
        If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase("C@f.com")) Then
            
            myFwd.Recipients.Add ("A@x.com")
            myFwd.Recipients.Add ("B@f.com")
        
            xStr1 = "<p>B1</p>"
            xStr2 = "<p>B2</p>"
            
            GoTo commonOutput
                            
        End If
        
    End If
End If
        
' If the mail is sent TO A@f.com -> AutoForward To A@x.com
If InStr(LCase(Item.To), LCase("A@f.com")) Then
    myFwd.Recipients.Add ("A@x.com")
    xStr1 = "<p>A1</p>"
    xStr2 = "<p>A2</p>"
    
    GoTo commonOutput
    
End If

MsgBox "None of the conditions was true, abort."
Exit Sub

commonOutput:
    With myFwd
        .HtmlBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HtmlBody
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is simple and solved my problem completely.

Comment: Do I need to reset Recipients, xStr1, xStr2 after every auto forward? If yes, could you please guide me?

Comment: New values for Recipients, xStr1, xStr2 will be determined each time the code runs.

Comment: I'm trying to add Cc, I use the following code and it show an error, can you help me? Please see my edit.  Set CcMember = myFwd.Recipients.Add ("A@f.com")  CcMember.Type = 2

Comment: Search for example with "[outlook*] [vba*] cc recipient" . Post a new question if you do not find an answer.

Comment: I fixed my issue.